HTML map buttons not getting the data
I'm new to HTML and JS but, I'm trying to build an interactive map using Mapbox.
I showing a dual case data that vary depending on the year. As you can see in the image, I would like to swithch between years a showing a different party name.

The thing is that I'm doing something wrong compared to my previous code as now I the buttons seems that they do not picking the data when clicking on them.
Here's my current code (I asked ChatGPT for help but I'm not sure how to properly debug the code):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
  <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
  <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
  <title>Elecciones Parlamento Catalunya 2024 - Municipios - La Vanguardia</title>
  <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
  <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v2.3.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v2.3.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="./styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="map-wrapper">
    <div id="map-container"></div>
    <!-- map controls -->
    <div id="custom-controls" class="map-overflow map-controls hidden">
      <div class="map-overflow-wrap">
        <div class="map-controls-hint">Selecciona un mapa:</div>
        <div class="map-controls-years">
          <button class="map-control map-control--year js-year is-active" data-year="2024">2024</button>
          <button class="map-control map-control--year js-year" data-year="2021">2021</button>
        </div>
        <div class="map-controls-fill">
          <!-- Botones para 2024 -->
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="PSC" data-year="2024">PSC</button>
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="ERC" data-year="2024">ERC</button>
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="JXCAT" data-year="2024">JUNTS</button>
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="VOX" data-year="2024">VOX</button>
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="SUMAR" data-year="2024">SUMAR</button>
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="CUP" data-year="2024">CUP</button>
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="CS" data-year="2024">CS</button>
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="PP" data-year="2024">PP</button>
          <!-- Botones para 2021 -->
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="PSC" data-year="2021">PSC</button>
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="ERC" data-year="2021">ERC</button>
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="JXCAT" data-year="2021">JUNTS</button>
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="VOX" data-year="2021">VOX</button>
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="CUP" data-year="2021">CUP</button>
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="CS" data-year="2021">CS</button>
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="PP" data-year="2021">PP</button>
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="ECP" data-year="2021">ECP</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end map controls -->

    <!-- map zoom out -->
    <div id="custom-buttons" class="map-overflow map-buttons hidden">
      <button id="zoom-out" class="zoom-out" title="Zoom out">
        <img src="img/catalunya.png" alt="Zoom out">
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- end map zoom out -->

    <!-- legend -->
    <div id="legends" class="map-legends hidden">
      <div class="map-legends-wrap">
        <header id="legends-head" class="map-legends-header"></header>
        <div id="legends-body" class="map-legends-body"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end legend -->
  </div>
  <script src="./map.js"></script>
  <script src="./partyColors.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      const yearButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.js-year');
      const fillButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.map-control--fill');

      function updateButtonsByYear(selectedYear) {
        fillButtons.forEach(button => {
          button.style.display = button.dataset.year === selectedYear ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
        });
      }

      yearButtons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', function() {
          console.log('Year button clicked:', this.dataset.year);
          yearButtons.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('is-active'));
          this.classList.add('is-active');
          updateButtonsByYear(this.dataset.year);
        });
      });

      const initialYear = document.querySelector('.js-year.is-active').dataset.year;
      updateButtonsByYear(initialYear);

      function loadMap() {
        const isMobile = window.innerWidth < 900;
        const map = new ElectionMap('public key', {
        container: 'map-container',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/fserrey/clvzejo7w014w01qu65sg9uau', 
        source: 'mapbox://fserrey.electionscat2021_adm4?fresh=true',       
        sourceLayer: 'electionscat2021_adm4',
        center: [1.55, 41.82],
        zoom: isMobile ? 7 : 8,
        minZoom: isMobile ? 5.5 : 6,
        initialSelect: 'winner2024',
        // hash: true,
        scrollZoom: true,
        years: [2021, 2024],
          parties: ['PP', 'PSOE', 'CS', 'ERC', 'PSC', 'JXCAT', 'PDCAT', 'ECP', 'CUP', 'COMUNS', 'SUMAR', 'VOX'],
          partyColors: window._partyColors,
        });
      }

      loadMap();
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>

My previous code (that works):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
  <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
  <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
  <title>Elecciones Parlamento Catalunya 2024 - Municipios - La Vanguardia</title>
  <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
  <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v2.3.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v2.3.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="./styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="map-wrapper">
    <div id="map-container"></div>

    <!-- map controls -->
    <div id="custom-controls" class="map-overflow map-controls hidden">
      <div class="map-overflow-wrap">
        <div class="map-controls-hint">Selecciona un mapa:</div>
        <div class="map-controls-years">
          <button class="map-control map-control--year js-year is-active" data-year="2024">2024</button>
          <button class="map-control map-control--year js-year" data-year="2021">2021</button>
          <!-- <button class="map-control map-control--year js-year" data-year="diff">Diff</button> -->
        </div>
        <div class="map-controls-fill">
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control is-active" data-fill="winner">Ganador</button>
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="PSC">PSC</button>
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="ERC">ERC</button>
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="JXCAT">JUNTS</button>
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="VOX">VOX</button>
          
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="CUP">CUP</button>
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="Sumar">SUMAR</button>
          
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="UP">ECP</button>

          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="PP">PP</button>
          
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="Bloques">Bloques</button>
          <!--
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="UP">Podemos</button>
          <button class="map-control map-control--fill js-control" data-fill="Sumar">Sumar</button>
          //-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end map controls -->

    <!-- map zoom out -->
    <div id="custom-buttons" class="map-overflow map-buttons hidden">
      <button id="zoom-out" class="zoom-out" title="Zoom out">
        <img src="img/catalunya.png" alt="Zoom out">
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- end map zoom out -->

    <!-- legend -->
    <div id="legends" class="map-legends hidden">
      <div class="map-legends-wrap">
        <header id="legends-head" class="map-legends-header"></header>
        <div id="legends-body" class="map-legends-body"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end legend -->

  </div>
  <script src="./map.js"></script>
  <script src="./partyColors.js"></script>
  <script>
    let mapLoaded = false;
    mapboxgl.clearStorage();

    const loadMap = () => {
      const isMobile = window.innerWidth < 900;
      const map = new ElectionMap('public key', {
        container: 'map-container',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/fserrey/clvzejo7w014w01qu65sg9uau', 
        source: 'mapbox://fserrey.electionscat2021_adm4?fresh=true',       
        sourceLayer: 'electionscat2021_adm4',
        center: [1.55, 41.82],
        zoom: isMobile ? 7 : 8,
        minZoom: isMobile ? 5.5 : 6,
        initialSelect: 'winner2024',
        // hash: true,
        scrollZoom: true,
        years: [2021, 2024],
        parties: ['PP', 'PSOE', 'CS', 'ERC', 'PSC', 'JXCAT','PDECAT','UP','CUP','COMUNS', 'SUMAR', 'VOX'],
        partyColors: window._partyColors,
      });
      mapLoaded = true;
    }

    // Remove Mapbox service worker cache
    if (caches && caches.keys()) {
      caches.keys().then((keys) => {
        Promise.all(keys.filter((k) => k === 'mapbox-tiles').map((k) => caches.delete(k)))
          .then(() => { loadMap() })
          .catch(() => { loadMap() });
      })
    } else loadMap();

    // Fallback if map has not been loaded
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (!mapLoaded) loadMap();
    }, 4000);
    
  </script>
</body>
</html>

I tried to add a listener to the buttons but when clicking on them, there's no data. I tried to put console logs but everything seems fine. I believe is related to how I'm calling the function map, but I would be really thankfull is someone cna bring some light to his problem.
Thank you all in advance!

That's really hard to read, you could look into php, and research about include statements, that way you can include chunks of code from other files. .php files can work exactly as .html, but you need to run them on server, for example in xampp

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
